# I want to amend each line in a Text file using sed or alternative solution

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to amend each line in a Text file using sed or alternative solution

input.txt containing

```
line 1
line 2 
line 3 
...
```

output.txt should add two strings  and

```
<before> line 1 and <after each line>
<before> line 2 and <after each line>
<before> line 3 and <after each line>
...
```

Can I use sed or something else?

Comment: Sample text please

Comment: original line : line 1 ..... after  <before> line 1 and <after each line>

Answer (score 11):

With sed:

```
sed 's/.*/<before> & and <after each line>/' input.txt > output.txt
```

#### Explanations

- `s/x/y/` – substitute x by y
- `.*` – take the whole line
- `&` – get matched text

The rest is just the text you want to add before and after `&`.

Comment: You could use just `.*` without the group and then `&` to get the complete matched text.

Comment: @ConfluentesInfo you should accept this answer in that case. See https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 8):

With awk:

```
awk '{print before, $0, after}' before="<before>" after="and <after each line" input.txt > output.txt
```

This just prints the contents of the variable `before`, `$0` (the current line) and the variable `after`, separated by spaces. The variables are set after the awk expression.

Answer (score 5):

With [`perl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/perl.1.html):

```bash
perl -ne 'chomp; print "<before> $_ and <after each line>\n"' in.txt > out.txt
```

These changes might be useful:

- Replace *`<before>`* and *`and <after each line>`* with whatever you actually want to add.
- Remove `> out.txt` to send the output to your terminal rather than to a file.
- You can remove the input filename (`in.txt`) an enter input interactively for testing.

How it works:

- `-p` makes the Perl interpeter operate on each line (see `perldoc perlrun` or [`man perlrun`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/perlrun.1.html)).
- `-e` causes the next argument to be a perl script. So the part in `'` `'` is Perl code.
- `chomp` removes the line terminator (newline) at the end of each line `perl` receives.
- `"` `"` quoted string support interpolation. `$_` is the line read. `\n` is a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character.
- `perl` will use `in.txt` as the input file. The `>` in `> out.txt` tells your shell to [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) output.

This command has the same effect, since `-p` (unlike `-n`) automatically prints each line (`$_`):

```bash
perl -pe 'chomp; $_ = "<before> $_ and <after each line>\n"' in.txt > out.txt
```

There are more `sed`-like ways to use `perl`. One advantage of the ways shown here is readability.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use coreutils:

```
n=$(wc -l < infile)
paste -d '' <(yes '<before>' | head -n $n) \
            infile                         \
            <(yes '</after>' | head -n $n)
```

Output:

```
<before>line 1</after>
<before>line 2</after>
<before>line 3</after>
```

Answer (score 4):

With [`vi`/`vim`/`ex`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/vim.1.html), you can write a non-interactive one-liner for this, or do it in an open editor.

You can use either of these commands from your shell. They open the editor, add text to the beginning and end of each line, save the file with a different filename, and quit the editor:

```bash
ex in.txt '+%s/.*/<before> & and <after each line>/' '+wq out.txt'
```

```bash
vi in.txt '+%s/.*/<before> & and <after each line>/' '+wq! out.txt'
```

The first command uses `ex` mode and `wq` is sufficient to save the buffer as `out.txt` and quit. The second command uses `vi` mode and, since the changed buffer is still open and has not been saved into the *original* file, it requires the `!` version of the  command.

The second command also works in `ex` mode (and with `vim` instead of `vi`) but there's no reason to avoid `ex` for one-liners. The real reason I show the `vi` version that you can use it, with `:` instead of `+` in each command, to perform the change interactively while editing interactively in `vi` or `vim`.

With `in.txt` open in the editor (`vim in.txt`) you can run:

```vim
:%s/.*/<before> & and <after each line>/
:wq! out.txt
```

Whether your use the noninteractive or interactive version, they work the same way. `vi` and `vim` (and many other text editors in the "`vi` family") support search and replace with a `sed`-like syntax. You will notice the similarity to [the `sed` method in dessert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/954329/22949):

- `.*` is a regular expression that matches any character (`.`) zero or more times (`*`), thereby matching a whole line.
- `&` signifies the whole match.
- `s/pattern/replacement/` replaces the first occurrence of *`pattern`* on a line with *`replacement`*.

`sed` automatically applies its script on *each* line. `vi`/`vim`/`ex` gives you more fine-grained control. `%s` performs the search and replace (`s`) action on *all lines* (`%`) and could also have been written `1,$s`. If you wanted to change just one line you could write something like `3s` (just the third line). Similarly you can change any range of lines, e.g., `3,10s` for the third through tenth lines or `10,$s` the tenth and all higher-numbered lines.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` and `sed`

```
awk 'NF' input.txt | sed -r 's/(.*)/<before> \1 and <after line>/' > out.txt
```

Explanation:

1. `awk` command removes blank lines and pipes the output to `sed`
2. `sed` captures each line and adds the needed texts before and after the returned value `\1` and redirects the out to `out.txt` file